# WDAC policy doesnt disable

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-defender

I'm trying to disable my device guard policy, what I have done is: windows + R --> gpedit.msc --> Local Computer Policy --> Computer configuration --> Administrative templates --> System --> Device guard --> Deploy Windows Defender Application Control --> Set to not configured as shown on image

[image: DEVICE GUARD NOT CONFIGURED]

Then I open msinfo32.exe to check if the policy is still active, System Summary --> Windows defender Aplication --> is set to audit as shown on image

[image: audit and not disabled]

How can I disable this policy??

Comment: Try asking at SuperUser for stand-alone workstation case, at ServerFault for domain-joined computers. This doesn't seem to be a programming question, so it's out of SO's scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it doing this in powershell:
rm "C:\Windows\System32\CodeIntegrity\SiPolicy.p7b"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CITool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/operations/citool-commands) to remove deployed unsigned WDAC policies.

If the WDAC policy is signed, [here is the official method for removal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/disable-windows-defender-application-control-policies).

I've created a PowerShell module that automates all of these processes (and a lot more):

Available on GitHub and PowerShell gallery

- https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/WDACConfig
- https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WDACConfig/

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue after deploying Intune default application control policy. After much hassle I solved this by delete all the files in Windows\System32\AppLocker. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I solved it deleting C:\Windows\System32\CodeIntegrity\SiPolicy.p7b which is the file that enforces the policy on the computer